# Ramda fails with setDate function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to learn functional javascript with [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) and I'm stuck with this. Here is the JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/kozeka/

And this is the code:

```
const date = new Date()
const addDays = R.add(date.getDate())
const getDate = R.compose(date.setDate, addDays)

console.log(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6)) //Works
console.log(date.setDate(R.add(date.getDate(), 6))) // Works
console.log(date.setDate(addDays(6))) //Works
console.log(getDate(6)) //Doesn't Work
```

But I got this error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
"TypeError: Method Date.prototype.setDate called on incompatible receiver undefined
    at setDate (<anonymous>)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js:6:3064
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js:6:182
    at kozeka.js:10:38"
```

Comment: So where does the functional programming come in ?

Comment: @naomik: Ramda is "A practical functional library for Javascript programmers"; `R.compose(date.setDate, addDays)` is functional programming.

Comment: @Amadan functional programming is more than just using Ramda or a function composition.

Comment: @naomik: So? JavaScript is more than `getElementsByClassName`; do you feel also that "How do I get elements if I have a class name in JavaScript" shouldn't be tagged as [tag:javascript]?

Comment: @Amadan that's a bit dramatic. I ask because the code posted here is a huge slurry of oop style, imperative style, referentially opaque functions, and side effects – these go against the grain of functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `setDate` loses the bound `date` instance when passed as a function.

This can be resolved by explicitly binding the method to the `date` instance when passing it to `compose`:

```
const getDate = R.compose(date.setDate.bind(date), addDays)
```